# How to execute a manually-written query or stored procedure in ZF2

Tags: php, sql-server, zend-framework2

I'm following the tutorial at http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html, and I have set up my `Module::getServiceConfig()` and my `AlbumTable` class as they've shown.

Now say I need to execute a stored procedure to get my result set...not a standard `SELECT`. I still want the result set to be a collection of `Album` models. How can this be done?

Here's an example of what I've tried:

**AlbumTable.php:**

```
public function findByArtist($artist) {
    $adapter = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter();
    $result = $adapter->query(
        "EXEC spGetAlbums @artist = :artist",
        array(':artist' => $artist)
    );

    var_dump($result->current());
}
```

The problem with this is that the `$result` returned is a collection of `ArrayObject`s...not a collection of `Album` models. So how can I execute the stored procedure but still get the results according to what I've set up in `Module::getServiceConfig()`?

Please don't bother asking what my stored procedure is doing...that's irrelevant to this question. Point is, it returns results that are compatible with the `Album` model.
<sub>^ Not meant to be attitude, just trying to save everyone the time of suggesting that I don't need to use a stored procedure.</sub>

Comment: You need to manually hydrate the ArrayObjects into an Album-Object. Since there you're doing a native SQL-Query, there's no other magic happening ;)

Comment: Is there no way to execute a native SQL query on a `TableGateway` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Sam suggested in the question comments, there doesn't appear to be a way to execute a native SQL query on a `TableGateway` object, so you would have to manually hydrate the data object.

After looking at Zend's Docs on [`HydratingResultSet`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.result-set.html#zend-db-resultset-hydratingresultset), here's the solution I came up with:

```
namespace Album\Table;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\HydratingResultSet;
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator;

class Album {

    protected $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway) {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function findByArtist($artist) {
        $adapter = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter();
        $result = $adapter->query(
            "EXEC spGetAlbums @artist = :artist",
            array(':artist' => $artist)
        );

        $dataSource = $result->getDataSource();
        if ($dataSource instanceof \Iterator) {
            $result = new HydratingResultSet(
                new Hydrator\ArraySerializable(),
                new \Album\Model\Album()
            );
            $result->initialize($dataSource);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I didn't really get what was going on with the `ReflectionHydrator`. It was populating my object via reflection, and it was not calling my `exchangeArray()` method. I realized this when I went to convert a `smalldatetime` value from the database into a `\DateTime` object in my `exchangeArray()` method...it wasn't getting called.

The fix for this was to use an `ArraySerializable` hydrator instead. So I've updated the code above to demonstrate this.

If you wanted the hydrator to use your setters (like `setArtist()` and `setTitle()`), you could use the `ClassMethods` hydrator.

If your properties are public (or if you're using a magic `__set()` method), you could use the `ObjectProperty` hydrator and it will just assign the values to your properties.

Comment: Good answer ;) The first parameter of the `HydratingResultSet` could be changed to other possible Hydrators like `ClassMethodsHydrator` or your own hydrator

Comment: @Sam: Took me a while to realize the difference between the hydrators, but I finally figured it out and updated my answer with more info that will hopefully be helpful to others.